# Pagination calling APIs data again in django

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am working on a project where I have to pass several projects ids to API calls. I am storing that in a list and on that list I am using paginator.
But when I access the next page again the whole view gets called and it makes those API calls again instead of taking it from the stored list.

```
     for i in rt:
         t = requests.get('https://wstest2.xtm-intl.com/rest-api/projects/' + str(i['id']), headers=headers,verify=False)
         tt = t.json()
         print('yo')
         targetlist.append(tt)

     mylist=list(zip(rt,targetlist))
     page=request.GET.get('page',1)
     paginator = Paginator(mylist, 10)
     pagelist=paginator.get_page(page)
     context={'pagelist':pagelist}
     return render(request,'dashboard/home.html',context)
```

Comment: A paginator can use limits for querysets (database calls). BUt it can not paginate a list that you construct yourself. It might thus be better to first capture the items from the API and store these in a model.

Comment: When you fetch a new page, you're making a new HTTP request to your Django app. That means your view API is called for every new page anyway, no way to avoid that. And therefore the QuerySet or list that is being paginated needs to be constructed again. If building the list takes a long time because you're making a 3rd party request, you should consider storing/caching the result the first time and grab it from cache/storage the next times.